# Firebase Integration for crash report without using cloud messaging

Tags: android

E/FA: GoogleService failed to initialize, status: 10, Missing google app id value from from string resources with name google_app_id.
 E/FA: Scheduler not set. Not logging error/warn
 E/FA: Missing google_app_id. Firebase Analytics disabled.
 E/FA: Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled